# Does Azure Workbook parameters not store results from custom endpoints?

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have a use case where I need to build a dynamic dropdown using data from a 3rd party endpoint:
[image]

The issue is that when setting up the parameter, all is great! However, when you want to use it, suddenly the parameter doesn't have all the values:
[image]

Is that an expected behavior? Does Azure Workbooks not store the data from a custom endpoint for its parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks doesn't store the values returned by the endpoint, it only stores the *selected* value.  The next time you open the workbook, it will re-run the query.

For custom endpoints, other users might have the red x that says it couldn't run the query because the host isn't trusted, so there are no values until they add the site to their trusted list.